# How to use react-compose if we want to pass data from one component to another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use react-compose to send data from one component to another but I am unable to relate how to do it ?

Comment: trying to use react compose to display the age from NameDefinition cmp to NameDisplay cmp, but unable to get so. Can anybody tell what exactly needs to be done, what mistake I am making ?

Comment: NameDefinition  cmp code :  


import React, { Component } from 'react'


const NameDefinition = {
    age:5
}

export default NameDefinition

Comment: NameDisplay cmp code : 

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import compose from 'react-compose'
import NameDefinition from './NameDefinition';


const NameDisplay = props => {
  return <p> {props.age} </p>; 
};

const Composed = compose(NameDefinition)(NameDisplay)

export default NameDisplay

Comment: App.js cmp code : 

import React from 'react';
import './App.css'; 
import NameDefinition from './components/NameDefinition';
import NameDisplay from './components/NameDisplay';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NameDisplay/>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: getting error as : 

TypeError: react_compose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a function

Comment: My friend, when someone asks you for more info, please add it in question so that relative audience gets update and you can get resolution quicker